# Как отправлять запросы из стороннего скрипта на другом пк в бота aiogram 3?

Tags: python, aiogram, requests, post, webhook

Мне нужно отправлять post запросы с какими то данными телеграмм боту, который работает на впс сервере. Бот в свою очередь должен отлавливать этот запрос и запускать какую-то функцию\хендлер и сохранять принятые данные. Как это можно реализовать? Весь бот работает через лонг поллинг.